# What cryptographic librairies will help calculate shared point and derive keys?

Tags: ecdsa, hsm, ecdh

We need to perform some cryptographic operations and I want to know what cryptographic librairies can fit my need.

The following is the context:

***Given the fact that we have:***

- An EC Private Key stored in the **HSM**
- An EC Public Key (public point)
- Encrypted AES key
- MAC calculated with the EC public key ECDH

***We need to perform the following:***

- **Calculate** a **shared point** (K~X~, K~Y~) using ECKA-DH algorithm from the EC Private and EC Public Keys. (See BSI TR 03111)
- **Derive** K~ENC~ and K~MAC~ using KDF2(x, l) with SHA-256. K~ENC~ is first 8 bytes of output. K~MAC~ is last 8 bytes of output. (See ISO/IEC 18033-2)
- Verify the MAC over the encrypted AES key against MAC ==> MAC = **AES-CMAC**(Encrypted AES key || ValueA || ValueB, K~MAC~).
- Decrypt the encrypted AES key ==> AES key = **AES-CBC**(encrypted AES key, K~ENC~).

> What cryptographic librairies will help calculate shared point baed on
>   the fact that the Private key is stored in the HSM?
>
> Can Bouncy Castle be used jointly with IAIK PKCS#11 wrapper?
>
> Can IAIK-JCE a commercial product from IAIK help on that?

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using HSM (your Elliptic Curve private is store on HSM) you can use API's from hsm vendors to perform your cryptographic operations. For eg: In case of Safenet HSM, Gemalto provides crystoki library like JSP and JCProv API's in java to perform all the operations you have stated.